# Getting 'Type mismatch' Run-time error when comparing values in different/separate table columns

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, type-mismatch

Basically I just want to check if two cells in a separate table columns contain the same string, and if they do, I want to assign another string just an ***.Offset(, 1)*** away from the original cell.

I'm trying to solve this for several hours now.
I've also tried comparing ***.text*** properties and converting with ***CStr()*** but still getting mismatch error.

Here's a sample

```
Dim c1 As Range
Dim c2 As Range

For Each c1 In tranTab.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
    For Each c2 In rawTab.DataBodyRange.Columns(9)
        If c2.Value = c1.Value Then
            c2.Value = c1.Offset(, 1).Value
        End If
    Next c2
Next c1
```

Debug highlights this line:

```
If c2.Value = c1.Value Then
```

and throws:

> 'Type mismatch' Run-time error

In **Locals** window both are shown as ***Variant/Variant*** type.
It's my first post/question and I'm almost sure I've done my research to find every similar piece of info about mismatch issues but none exhausting the topic when it comes to operating on *tables/ListObjects*.

Comment: A column is an entire range - you can't compare one column to another like that.

Comment: @BigBen isn't OP looping through the columns?

Comment: @Damian - trying comparing one *column* to another. `c1` and `c2` aren't single cells, they are columns.

Comment: isn't `For each c1 in tranTab.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)` the same as `For each c1 in ws.Range("A:A")` ?

Comment: @BigBen no, OP is selecting that each column and iterating the cells in those columns.

Comment: @Damian. No. Try it. `Range` doesn't work the same way as `Columns`.

Comment: @ScottCraner - that's not correct. You'd need to be explicit about the `.Cells`.

Comment: So if the OP adds `.Cells` to each it should work as long as there are no errors in the data?

Comment: @ScottCraner correct, and if there's no line that tries to compare a number to text.

Comment: Something we learned today @BigBen :)

Comment: @Damian I'm pretty sure I learned it similarly a while back :)

Comment: While this now clears how you iterate a range properly. You might also want to learn how to iterate an array thought memory (faster) and also, it seems you might just want to use `.Find` on the second column instead of a constant iteration. Good luck with your future codings =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop is not through cells, but it is through the whole column. Try this and check that the address is the one of the column:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim c1 As Range
    For Each c1 In Worksheets(1).ListObjects("tranTab").DataBodyRange.Columns(1)
        Debug.Print c1.Address
    Next c1

End Sub
```

In order to loop through the cells, add `.Cells` at the end of the for-each loop:

```
For Each c1 In Worksheets(1).ListObjects("tranTab").DataBodyRange.Columns(1).Cells
```

Comment: Upvoted. This is not the first time I've encountered confusion about looping through `Columns` or `Rows`, and how their behavior is not the same as referencing a column or row as a `Range`.

Comment: @BigBen - true & thanks. If VBA was to be ever updated, maybe it will be a good idea, to obtain some kind of a feature, disabling looping through a single column() without adding cells to it.

Comment: .... "if VBA was to be ever updated".... hehe, good luck with that :)

Comment: .... "if VBA was to be ever updated" I can make a *very* long list for that :)

Comment: @BigBen - At first I thought about writing "This could be a good feature for the [UserVoice](https://excel.uservoice.com//), but then I considered the VBA-update thing... :)

Comment: Thanks, that was confusing indeed but I'm glad I've learned the difference :)